# Celery + Redis how to run tasks based on lowest timestamp with same priority

Tags: celery, celery-task

I have defined a task in celery and it been called using flask framework. I see the celery is able to execute the tasks on worker node. Now lets say some API called the tasks in this fashion.

```
 timestamp, task_id, priority
(t0, task1, P0)
(t1, task2, P0)
(t2, task3, P1)
```

When I monitor the task status sometimes I see that task2 is finishing before the task1. How can I reliably expect the celery to finish the task1 first then it should pick task2 as task1 was submitted before task2.

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using redis, what celery queue prioritization guarantees is that the first arriving tasks **will be taken off the queue** first (and, roughly speaking start first), not that first arriving tasks **finish** first.  If you want to guarantee that tasks finish in the order that they are received, you have to (1) ensure that there is only one worker consuming off the queue, (2) set `worker_prefetch_multiplier` to 1, and (3) set concurrency to 1 when the worker is started.